# is it possible to append text horizontally using StreamWriter c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I'm using the `Kinect` and can save the tracking coordinates to a text file, but I need the appended text horizontal (left to right) for each X and Y coordinate in order to draw graphs. At the moment the text looks like this:

```
2:58:22 PM

Head X      314

Head Y      250

2:58:22 PM

Head X      314

Head Y      251
```

but I'm trying to get it like this:

```
2:58:22 PM               2:58:23 PM

Head X  1   2   3   4  5   6   7  8  9 

Head Y  1   2   3   4  5   6   7  8  9
```

Here is my code for saving to a text file:

```
StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("Text.txt");
sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

sw.WriteLine("Head X   " + "\t" + TextBox21.Text);
sw.WriteLine("Head Y   " + "\t" + TextBox41.Text);

sw.WriteLine("Shoulder X" + "\t" + TextBox22.Text);
sw.WriteLine("Shoulder Y" + "\t" + TextBox42.Text);

sw.WriteLine("ShoulderLeft X" + "\t" + TextBox23.Text);
sw.WriteLine("ShoulderLeft Y" + "\t" + TextBox43.Text);

sw.WriteLine("ShoulderRight X" + "\t" + TextBox24.Text);
sw.WriteLine("ShoulderRight Y" + "\t" + TextBox44.Text);

sw.WriteLine("ElbowLeft X" + "\t" + TextBox25.Text);
sw.WriteLine("ElbowLeft Y" + "\t" + TextBox45.Text);

sw.WriteLine("ElbowRight X" + "\t" + TextBox26.Text);
sw.WriteLine("ElbowRight Y" + "\t" + TextBox46.Text);

sw.WriteLine("WristLeft X" + "\t" + TextBox27.Text);
sw.WriteLine("WristLeft Y" + "\t" + TextBox47.Text);

sw.WriteLine("WristRight X" + "\t" + TextBox28.Text);
sw.WriteLine("WristRight Y" + "\t" + TextBox48.Text);

sw.WriteLine("HandLeft X" + "\t" + TextBox29.Text);
sw.WriteLine("HandLeft Y" + "\t" + TextBox49.Text);

sw.WriteLine("HandRight X" + "\t" + TextBox30.Text);
sw.WriteLine("HandRight Y" + "\t" + TextBox50.Text);

sw.WriteLine("Spine X   " + "\t" + TextBox31.Text);
sw.WriteLine("Spine Y   " + "\t" + TextBox51.Text);

sw.WriteLine("HipCenter X" + "\t" + TextBox32.Text);
sw.WriteLine("HipCenter Y" + "\t" + TextBox52.Text);

sw.WriteLine("HipLeft X" + "\t" + TextBox33.Text);
sw.WriteLine("HipLeft Y" + "\t" + TextBox53.Text);

sw.WriteLine("HipRight X" + "\t" + TextBox34.Text);
sw.WriteLine("HipRight Y" + "\t" + TextBox54.Text);

sw.WriteLine("KneeLeft X" + "\t" + TextBox35.Text);
sw.WriteLine("KneeLeft Y" + "\t" + TextBox55.Text);

sw.WriteLine("KneeRight X" + "\t" + TextBox36.Text);
sw.WriteLine("KneeRight Y" + "\t" + TextBox56.Text);

sw.WriteLine("AnkleLeft X" + "\t" + TextBox37.Text);
sw.WriteLine("AnkleLeft Y" + "\t" + TextBox57.Text);

sw.WriteLine("AnkleRight X" + "\t" + TextBox38.Text);
sw.WriteLine("AnkleRight Y" + "\t" + TextBox58.Text);

sw.WriteLine("FootLeft X" + "\t" + TextBox39.Text);
sw.WriteLine("FootLeft Y" + "\t" + TextBox59.Text);

sw.WriteLine("FootRight X" + "\t" + TextBox40.Text);
sw.WriteLine("FootRight Y" + "\t" + TextBox60.Text);

sw.Close();
```

Comment: sorry image from excel did not upload, will try again

Comment: use `Write` instead of WriteLine http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce2kyyb4.aspx

Comment: Did you mean to use `Write` instead of `WriteLine`? `WriteLine` makes each entry onto a new line.

Answer (score 0):

`sw.Write` will allow you to write inline text.

`WriteLine` creates a line-break.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the "Line"-part of WriteLine, and just use Write?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here, but I think perhaps you just want to use `Write()` instead of `WriteLine()`

`WriteLine()` will add a line break at the end. So what you want is as follows:

```
sw.Write("Head X   " + "\t" + TextBox21.Text);
```

you may also need to consider adding an extra delimiter, but that depends on what you need as output.